# Equivalent of memmove on files: copy a range of bytes to an earlier position

Tags: files, dd

What is an equivalent of memmove on files with the same input and output file, which works with large files?

`dd` works when I move the file contents towards the right, but not if I move the contents left, since there's no handling of overlap.

`ddrescue` has a reverse copy, but refuses to work on the same input & output file.

Comment: Is left or right the beginning or end? It can move closer to the beginning but not closer to the end, not without wrapping it in a loop that does it backwards.

Comment: Left is the beginning.

Comment: On Linux with some filesystem you could try [`fallocate`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187211/1321)

Answer (score 0):

`beav` is a visual binary editor with commands similar to `emacs` that can edit binary files. The sequence you would use to move a block would run along the lines of :

- find start of block and set mark <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>
- go to to end of block and delete-mark-to-cursor (contents stored in kill-buffer)<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>
- go to where you want the block moved to and yank <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>
- file-save <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
- quit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

Here's the Debian [beav](https://packages.debian.org/stable/beav) package description.

Extract

> With beav, you can edit a file in HEX, ASCII, EBCDIC, OCTAL, DECIMAL,
>   and BINARY. You can display but not edit data in FLOAT mode. You can
>   search or search and replace in any of these modes. Data can be
>   displayed in BYTE, WORD, or DOUBLE WORD formats. While displaying
>   WORDS or DOUBLE WORDS the data can be displayed in INTEL's or
>   MOTOROLA's byte ordering. Data of any length can be inserted at any
>   point in the file. The source of this data can be the keyboard,
>   another buffer, or a file. Any data that is being displayed can be
>   sent to a printer in the displayed format. Files that are bigger than
>   memory can be handled.

Comment: Does beav work with large (multi-terabyte) copy pastes without filling up ram?

Comment: You should [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/120714/edit) your original question and add that pertinent piece of information. I've added an extract, but haven't tried it with files that large. sorry